# Reading music file in android into a byte array?

Tags: android

I am trying to read the contents of music files from my android device though i have been able to retrieve the files and play them i need to read the music files and convert them in to a byte array. Can someone please help me :
Following is my code:

```
 public void retrieve_music_files() {
     music_column_index =   musiccursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA); 
     musiccursor.moveToPosition(position); 
     String filename = musiccursor.getString(music_column_index);
     Cursor musiccursor;
     MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
     int music_column_index;

     try {
         if (mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
             mMediaPlayer.reset();
         }
         mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(filename);
         mMediaPlayer.prepare();
         mMediaPlayer.start();
     } catch (Exception e) {
     }    
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with the byte array? Just pass it along to the audio system, or do some internal processing first?

Answer (score 1):

I used below code for my project. Hope this works for you.

```
String musicFilePath="your music file path";
byte[] fileByteArray;
File file = new File(musicFilePath);
fileByteArray = new byte[(int)file.length()];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to convert any file into an array of bytes following the code in this link.

http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-file-into-an-array-of-bytes/

Comment: This doesn't decode it down to a stream of uncompressed samples, however.